# Selecting specific fields from a relationship

Tags: node.js, waterline

I'm building a webapp on node.js (sails) with waterline (using mysql adapter).

I've managed to get relationships working like this:

```
//Post.js attributes
    post_statistics: {
        collection: 'postStatistics',
        via: 'post'
    }
```

I can easily find the relationship records with the line:

```
var query = {user:userId}; // Just filtering by the user
query.is_public = Post.POSTS_ONLY_ACTIVE; // Only showing active posts, boolean
query.select = ['id','title','content']; // id is only needed for me to get the join working
Post.find(query).populate('post_statistics').exec(cb);
```

Everything works fine but I need to only select specific fields from post_statistics.
This does not seem to do anything, though, I'd expect it to work:

```
Post.find(query).populate('post_statistics',{select:['post','user','id']}).exec(cb);
```

Adding the field names to the initial select is even worse since the fields already target the **post** table.

Any sane way to make this work or am I going to have to write the whole query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `.populate({ assoc, select: [] })` is not supported in waterline, more details in https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/919.

One possible alternative would be to run a SQL query via `.query()` ([docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/67545664138e7362640756dd97205142cc72cac9/query-methods.md#query-query-data-callback-)).

Another would be to submit a patch to [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/) adding support for `.populate({ assoc, select: [] })`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually done some research and waterline does seem to have support for select and it works wonders with the disk adapter. But I've tried switching it up to mysql-sails and it does not work there. So the problem must reside in mysql-sails then, I suppose.
Anyways, I'll do more commenting on github on the thread.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it's not on the [waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs) nor on the [waterline adapter tests](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-adapter-tests) so I wouldn't consider it "officially supported". In other words you may get lucky in a given adapter but since it's not explicitly supported a subsequent change may inadvertently break that behaviour.